# Magento 2 Index Controller - Display customer, product details on Custom Module

Tags: magento2, product, customer, sales, magento2.2.4

I have created the Custom module and also its Index controller file named Index.php in app/code/Companyname/Modulename/Controller/Index directory.

In that Index.php file, I have already added my custom function. Along with that I need to get Customer, Product, Sales, etc,. details in that index contoller.

How to display the customer, product, sales, etc details in my Custom module's Index controller file on Magento 2?

Here is my Index contoller **Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Companyname/Modulename/Controller/Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{



     public function myAction()
    {

            /*
           My CODE 
        */

    }


}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a page? or you want to show customer details by id etc?

Comment: I have added Order Form on Product detailed page. In that I can get the order and customer details, etc.

Comment: What do you want in your myAction function?

Comment: In that `myAction` function, I need to get the customer, store, order, etc, details. I can get the form details filled by customer by `$this->getRequest()->getParam()`

Comment: Which customer details and order details of which customer? Can you explain your requirement?

Comment: In that myAction function, I need to get the customer, store, order, etc, details. I can get the form details filled by customer by $this->getRequest()->getParam()